# How to Read data from .blm file and send it to SQL database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to read .blm file and store its data to SQL database,need your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry but this is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? You tried and you stuck somewhere? It would be better to show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: _@SonerGönül i do not  know how to do it.i want some direction to perform this task and i even do not know from where i should start._

Comment: @TT. thank you..problem solved now

Comment: You are most welcome. Good luck!